# How to assert that an element's text is not empty on playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm executing this line because I want to verify that heading has some text on it.

`await expect(page.locator('div.welcome-content > h2')).not.toBeEmpty;`

But when I execute it, that line does nothing, it's not asserting anything but also doesn't return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use the expect function with the .not.toBeEmpty matcher should include parentheses after .not.toBeEmpty to invoke the assertion and compare it to the actual value.

```js
await expect(page.locator('div.welcome-content > h2')).not.toBeEmpty()
```

If you are using playwrights own assertion library then you can do something like this,

```js
await expect(page.locator('div.welcome-content > h2')).toHaveText(text => text.length > 0);
```

Comment: That solved my problem. So whenever I use a function that I don't need to pass arguments to, I still should always use the parentheses?

Comment: when you call a function, you should always use parentheses, even if the function doesn't take any arguments.